# apex:inlineEditSupport call javascript function when value changes

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a pageblocktable which has outputfields, with inlineEditSupport. I need to call a javascript function whenever the fields are edited inline, but before saving. Apex:inlineEditSupport does not provide an attribute to do this. How can I get around this?

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Comment: Im having pretty much this same problem. I tried using apex:actionsupport to trigger a page re-render after an inline edit is made, but it doesn't work. I posted a question about it here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197860/rerender-section-of-page-when-field-is-inline-edited-without-saving It's been over 2 years since navD87 posted this... There's still no way to fire off a javascript function or trigger a page re-render when a field is inline edited in a vf page?!