# rerender section of page when field is inline edited without saving

Tags: visualforce, rerender, inlineeditsupport

Is there a way to re-render my VF page when a field is modified via inline editing without anything being saved? Right now I have the following snippet in my VF page:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!qli.Quantity}">                    
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
</apex:outputField>
```

I can double click on this field to change its value, then click outside of it to set that new value. At that point, nothing has actually been saved, but the new value I typed in is displayed in that outputField.

As soon as that field is modified, I would like to rerender a section of the page.

I tried using apex:actionsupport in my outputField with an "onchange" event, but it didn't work.

```
<!-- this does not work -->
<apex:outputField value="{!qli.Quantity}">
    <apex:actionSupport rerender="qliList" event="onchange" immediate="true"/>
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
</apex:outputField>
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried a few different hacks to make this work such as trying to attach an event listener to the field in Javascript, but Salesforce make this basically impossible since they change the id and class attributes of the element. I don't know of a reliable way to pull these elements in javascript to attach an event listener to them, and theres the further challenge of actually triggering a page re-render from JS which I'm not entirely sure how to do...

My problem cannot be solved by the solution offered by Shailendra Singh in [How can i call a method from apex:outputField (picklist) in visualforce page on inlineedit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/128044/49567)

Inline editing can only be done with outputfields. I specifically need an outputfield to use this feature. Inputfields are always editable, whereas outputfields are not editable by default unless they have inline editing enabled, at which point the user can double click on them to enable editing and change them. The solution Shailendra Singh offered in that other question involves changing the field from an outputfield to an inputfield, which is not what i need.

Comment: @Basti that is not the same issue. This is not a picklist field and I need it to be an output field. Inputfields cannot be inline-edited

Comment: Just an update, I've found a way to fire off a javascript function when the field is inline-edited. I created a method in my apex class called "rerender" and added a `<apex:actionFunction action="{!rerender}" name="rerenderqlist" rerender="qliList"/>` to the `<apex:pageBlock>` containing my outputField. Then I added a javascript event handler to each instance of the inputfield for a "change" event to fire this "rerenderqlist();" function. Unfortunately when the page re-renders, I lose the change to the field, it reverts back to its default value. Is there a way to make it keep the value?